# Reference about a hypergeometric identity

Tags: reference-request, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to find a reference for this hypergeometric identity:

http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.03.0021.01

Somebody can help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably  case 25 listed in https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3126 with n=1 there.